# how to compile with handlebars js as i do in mustache js

Tags: mustache, handlebars.js

This is mustache syntax, i want to do the same with handlebars. I dont want to use script blocks or anything like that. How do i compile the same code with handlebars js?

```
Handlebars.compile(template, data) //doesnt work.
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test"> </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var data = {
    name: "Parent",
    children: [{
        name: "Child"
    }]
};

var template = "{{name}} {{#children}} {{name}} {{/children}}";
var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
$('#test').html(html);
```

OUTPUT:
    Parent
    Child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
//Sourcecode
var source   = "<p>{{name}}, {{#each children}} {{name}} {{/each}}</p>";
//Compiling and creating our template
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
//Give te template our data
var html = template(data);
```

Output: Parent, Child